# How can set IV manualy in AES in php

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio-2010, aes

In c# iv is a byte[] an we can set it manualy. 
How can set it manualy in php?
We can set it in random. But i want to set that manualy. 
Thanks

Comment: By passing it as an argument to the crypto function.

Comment: Mr Amrollahi,I need to talk to you about an article on indexing,It is highly related to lucene,and I found your questions so close to what I am looking for,give me your e-mail please,or contact me on farnam7022@yahoo.com ,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set it before passing to mcrypt_generic_init ()

```
$iv = '1234567890123456';
mcrypt_generic_init ($td, $key, $iv);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic-init.php